# Boost Phoenix operator overload/redefinition?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-phoenix

Is there a (preferably easy) way to redefine one of the standard operators in Phoenix?   I would like to have ">>" for example call my own (lazy) functor.

Simple use case:  I might want to define a "pipeline" operator, so that:

```
function2(function1(arg1));
```

could be written in an extremely tricky fashion as

```
arg1 >> function1 >> function2
```

and then invoked as

```
(arg1 >> function1 >> function2)(42)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `arg1 >> function1 >> function2` can only be equivalent to `function2(function1(arg1))`. [Here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1gJygE$0) is an example.

Comment: @llonesmiz -  thanks, that was a typo... I've edited the question to fix.  Your example looks like an answer -- why not post it as such?

Comment: @llonesmiz please do, I want to be able to upvote it

Comment: @sehe I can't make it work with functors and I'm pretty sure there are problems with const correctness.

Comment: My example above does not work in either clang 3.2 or Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: [New version](http://liveworkspace.org/code/D6ISr$0) that works with g++, clang and VS. The need to use `BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_TR1` means that I'm doing something wrong with the result_of protocol, but I don't know enough to know exactly what. Something that must be very basic but I don't understand is that VS requires `&function` (much uglier) while g++ and clang accept `&function` and `function`. If someone wants to make an answer out of this, feel free.